# Setting Azure Pipelines -> Gradle -> JUnit -> Spring Boot environment variables correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline to run a build validation. One of my JUnit tests requires connecting to real Azure Blob Storage account, whose connection string is to be kept protected, and is already defined as a secret environment variable.

Tests are run via Azure Gradle task as shown later. So DevOps -> Gradle -> JUnit -> Spring Boot is the chain.

### Question

How do I pass a secret pipeline variable as an environment variable to a Spring JUnit 5 test using Azure Gradle Task?

How does IntelliJ IDEA inject environment variables, as shown below, into the Spring Boot environment of a JUnit test?

### Code

- OrbitProperties is a class annotated `@ConfigurationProperties(value = "it.orbit", ignoreInvalidFields = true)`
- `String azureConnectionString = orbitProperties.getFileRepository().getAzureStorageConnectionString();`

The `beforeEach` method has a kill-switch (a skip-switch to be precise) to skip the test if the connection string is not present

```
    assumeTrue(() -> isNotBlank(azureConnectionString));
```

### Local setup

Running IntelliJ IDEA, I can set the environment variable according to Spring convention: `IT_ORBIT_FILE_REPOSITORY_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING`

[image: IDEA setup]

Tests work, as I can see and debug them writing stuff to Azure.
Actually, even the production app works by setting the environment variable in Web App Configuration in Azure Portal.

### Pipelines setup

YAML

```
          - task: Gradle@3
            displayName: Build with Gradle
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              gradleOptions: -Xmx10240m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
              options: -Pci=true -PbuildId=$(Build.BuildId) -Preckon.stage=${{parameters.versionStage}} -Preckon.scope=${{parameters.versionScope}}
              jdkVersionOption: 1.11
              jdkArchitectureOption: x64
              publishJUnitResults: true
              sqAnalysisEnabled: true
              sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: specify
              sqGradlePluginVersion: 3.2.0
              testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
              tasks: clean build
            env:
              IT_ORBIT_FILE_REPOSITORY_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{variables.testStorageAccountConnectionString}}
```

As you can see, I have used the `env` key to the Gradle task to supply Gradle with custom environment. I have preferred this over `-D` Java properties because in the future I could get a lot more properties to inject into the environment.

I am currently trying in different ways. But the result is that the tests are skipped (because of the skip-switch) despite the test suite being successful. That's the purpose of skipping.

Comment: I made a copy/paste mistake, when I brought the variable to Java options I still used colon and space rather than equals, and no, the connection string has no whitespace

Comment: You forgot to say what problem you’re facing. Is your test skipped due to the absence of the variable?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar correct. I wrote the paragraphs in different order so I focused on the "how" other than the "what's wrong". I amended and yes, I confirm that the tests are skipped because the variable is unset

Answer (score 1):

Found the correct way in YAML

```
          - task: Gradle@3
            displayName: Build with Gradle
            inputs:
              gradleWrapperFile: gradlew
              gradleOptions: |
                -Xmx10240m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                -DIT_ORBIT_FILE_REPOSITORY_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(IT_ORBIT_FILE_REPOSITORY_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING)
              options: -Pci=true -PbuildId=$(Build.BuildId) -Preckon.stage=${{parameters.versionStage}} -Preckon.scope=${{parameters.versionScope}}
              jdkVersionOption: 1.11
              jdkArchitectureOption: x64
              publishJUnitResults: true
              sqAnalysisEnabled: true
              sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: specify
              sqGradlePluginVersion: 3.2.0
              testResultsFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/test-results/**/TEST-*.xml'
              tasks: clean build
            env:
              IT_ORBIT_FILE_REPOSITORY_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: $(testStorageAccountConnectionString)
```

### Explanation

Following [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch), it is explained that every secret variable **MUST** be mapped to an environment variable. What is not said explicitly is that Gradle doesn't get them injected directly once they are in the environment.

For that, you want to use `gradleOptions` (`javaOptions` didn't work quite well) and inject the `-D` property. The more connection strings or variables in general you need to inject from Gradle, the more code you'll have to write